# Perforce how many clients can I create?

Tags: perforce

I create a different client when working on different features in the same depot.
I was wondering if there's a limitation on the amount of clients that I can create ( can't find an answer for that )

And if it may cause some issues ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're working on a server that is licensed, there is no limit. If you're running on a server without a license, I believe the latest version of Perforce allows 20 users and 20 workspaces with unlimited files, or unlimited users and clients with 1000 files. Based this off the documentation for the [p4 license](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/license.html) command.

Comment: Thanks ! and do you think it's bad having a client per feature ? will that cause any performance/issues in perforce ?

Comment: Keeping a separate client per feature might eventually get a little unwieldy for you to manage, depending on the size of the depot (since you'll have multiple full copies of the depot on your HDD).

Comment: Personally, when I've used multiple clients, it was to allow me to work on more than one thing without getting the changelists crossed up. Or to have a "clean" workspace that I could use to verify my changes didn't cause an issue that I was seeing. Now I would use shelving to solve both of those problems.

Answer (score 1):

Each client workspace adds some additional information for the server to track. The impact on the server depends on scale. If your workspace has, say, 500 files sync'd, then the impact is very small. If you are planning on creating 100,000 workspaces, and each of them has 10,000,000 files sync'd, then the impact is significantly larger (but still manageable; I know of Perforce installations which handle numbers 50 times this large).

Recent versions of the server (2012.2 and higher) provide tools for your administrator to use to deal with excessive numbers of very large workspaces, so if that's what you have in mind you should probably have that conversation with your administrator so they're prepared to deploy those tools if necessary.

Comment: Please tell us of these Perforce installations with "5,000,000 workspaces, each with 500,000,000 files sync'd".  What are they doing that requires that number of users and files and users who need access to all those files?

Comment: @raven, often it is build automation. The actual number of users may only be in the thousands or tens of thousands, but modern Continuous Integration build systems drive a phenomenal load across the SCM system. Happily Perforce has lots of features for satisfying the requirements of those tools. But, in the end, it's usually programs driving that level of load, not humans.